# Three.js: building a tangent plane through point on a sphere

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, geometry

I am trying to build a tangent plane on a sphere that crosses particular point on the sphere's surface in Three.js (v0.129). My algorithm is the following:

1. Get the center of the sphere;
2. Find the radius vector crossing the given point;
3. Find the normal to the radius vector
4. Find the product of the radius vector and the normal vector, because the product of 2 vectors should be a vector that is perpendicular to both vectors;
5. Get the end points of the product vector and the normal vector and build a plane throgh those points - this should be tangent plane.

But for some reason the product is not always perpendicular to radius and the normal vectors. And I don't understand why, I tried to build just lines for all the vectors to visualize it and I get the following:

[image: Sphere]

The question is what am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to build the tangent plane to a sphere through the given point?

My code is the following:

```
const createTangentPlane = (point: THREE.Vector3, sphere: Entity) => {
sphere.object3D.updateMatrixWorld();

sphere.object3D.updateMatrix();

const center = sphere.object3D.position;
const radiusVector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(point, center).normalize();
const radiusNormal = radiusVector
    .clone()
    .applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI * 0.5)
    .normalize();
const a = radiusNormal.clone().normalize().setLength(10).add(point);
const b = radiusNormal.clone().normalize().negate().setLength(10).add(point);
const orthogonalVector = radiusVector.clone().cross(radiusNormal);
const a1 = orthogonalVector.clone().setLength(10).add(point);
const b1 = orthogonalVector.clone().negate().setLength(10).add(point);

createLine(([a1, b1]);
createLine([a, b]);
createLine([center, point]);

//createPlaneFrom4Points([a, a1, b1, b]);

}
```

Comment: Rotating a vector by 90° about the Z-axis (or X/Y for that matter) does not produce a perpendicular vector in the general case. You can instead take the cross-product of the radius vector with an arbitrary direction.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog you are right, my radiusNormal is absolutely wrong, getting another cross product made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

- `three.js r130` (`r129` should be fine)
- The position of the sphere
- The "tangent point" on the surface of the sphere (assuming it's a `Vector3`)

Assuming:

- The sphere position is in world coordinates
- The tangent point is also in world coordinates

```js
let normal = new THREE.Vector3().copy( tangentPoint )
normal.sub( sphere.position ) // remove sphere translation

let plane = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry( sphere.radius, sphere.radius )
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 'red' } )
)
plane.lookAt( normal )
plane.position.copy( tangentPoint )
```